# How to insert text from php to a mongo database

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm looking to insert the text input provided by user on a webpage in a text input field(comment box) I created using php, to a mongo database, how do I do that?

Comment: find out something on internet and try on your own, what you have tried??? It seems like you post to get code. There are lots of tutorials for very beginner programmers too.

Comment: It's people like you that give stackoverflow a bad name, if you don't know the answer, walk away.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to connect with Mongo Database then create collection and then insert the desire value in json format.

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();
   echo "Connection to database successfully";

   // select a database
   $db = $m->mydb;
   echo "Database mydb selected";
   $collection = $db->mycol;
   echo "Collection selected succsessfully";

   $inputTextValue= array( 
      "key" => "value",
   );
   $collection->insert($inputTextValue);
   echo "inputTextValue inserted successfully";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this code useful for you

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();
   echo "Connection to database successfully";

   // select a database
   $db = $m->mydb;
   echo "Database mydb selected";
   $collection = $db->mycol;
   echo "Collection selected succsessfully";

   $document = array( 
      "field_name" => "Your text input field "
   );

   $collection->insert($document);
   echo "Document inserted successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.